# Bring up first app in Android automotive 10

Tags: android-automotive

I am working on AOSP 10 for automotive platform .
I am stuck basically in how to bring app in emulator .

i have created an application in android studio like 5 buttons with some indication application. like status message on the button.

1. I am not aware or not getting info basically how to connect it with VHAL
2. Where do i need to place this application in AOSP 10 and what configurations i need to make to see it in the emulator.
3. if i click on the button then i need to send a message to car service layer.
   what i need to do to achieve this .

Basically am unclear on how the connections to be made and what i need to write in which layer

Thank you and appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a home app, then you'll follow steps posted on many different posts.
Else, I am not clear what your questions actually is asking for.

PS: Fix punctuation and capitalization, and please try to be specific.

Comment: Hi , I am able to bring first app in AOSP . Thank you for reply